# String separation in space areas

Tags: python, string, list

we have a string with spaces and we have max string length, i.e.

```
str1 = 'we have a string with spaces and we have max string length'
b=8
```

And divide string in rows with max b length in row, but we can divide only in space area.

Expected Output:

```
x='
we have
a string
with
spaces
and we
have max
string
length'
```

and it should work for any b.
I have tried to make a list from a string and check can two elements of list be less than b(but the can be 3 or 4 etc, so dont know what to do in this case).
!And very important that by the task description b is actually named as 'len' , so i believe this is made to prevent using this function...

```
str1 = 'we have a string with spaces and we have max string length'
def WordSearch(len:int, a:str->int:
    k=[]
    t=str1.split(sep=' ')
    z=str()
    lst1 = ['wp' + str(i) for i in range(len(t))]
    for j in lst1:
        for i in range(len(t)):
            if len(j)+len(t[i])<lenn:
                'wp0'+t[0]+' '

    print(lst1)
WordSearch(len=8,a=str1)
```

Is it possible to fix code? or i am going completely wrong way....

Comment: Well, for one your code won't work because you redefine `len` as a parameter, shadowing the function you're trying to use later on. Also your code is missing some parentheses, so you won't even get to the point of running it to find that out, as this just won't run. Add to that a typo (`lenn`?) and some mysterious choices for logic - and it's hard to see how this would ever work. Take it back a lot and start with something that does what you expect. Then take it forward one step at a time, until you find an actual problem - don't just throw code together and pray for it to work.

Comment: @Netbek What do you want as output ? EXPECTED OUTPUT

Comment: @ghost21blade
output: String with max X chars length on every row, words shouldn't be divided between letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some algorithm exercise, anyway it just need to take care of corner cases.

```
str1 = 'we have a string with spaces and we have max string length'
def WordSearch(len:int, a:str):
    k=[]
    first_str = ''
    first_len = 0
    second_str = ''
    second_len = 0
    is_first = True
    for c in a:
        if c == ' ':
            if is_first:
                is_first = False
                continue
            if first_len + second_len + 1 > len:
                k.append(first_str)
                first_str = second_str
                first_len = second_len
                second_str = ''
                second_len = 0
            else:
                first_str = first_str + ' ' + second_str
                first_len += second_len + 1
                second_str = ''
                second_len = 0
        else:
            if is_first:
                first_str += c
                first_len += 1
            else:
                second_str += c
                second_len += 1

    if second_len != 0:
        if first_len != 0:
            if (first_len + second_len + 1 > len):
                k.append(first_str)
                k.append(second_str)
            else:
                k.append(first_str + ' ' + second_str)
        else:
            k.append(second_str)
    elif first_len != 0:
        k.append(first_str)
    result = '\r\n'.join(k)
    print(result)
WordSearch(len=8,a=str1)
```

Comment: Try your code with *WordSearch(4, str1)*

Comment: @Stuart then parameter len must larger than longest word in str, otherwise the behavior is undefined

Comment: Surely it's up to you, the programmer, to define the behaviour. The requirement is very clear. So, if it can't be done, then I would suggest returning None or raising an exception

Comment: Thank you, sir! You have managed do it even without len func!

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
import textwrap
output = textwrap.wrap('we have a string with spaces and we have max string length', 8)
output == ['we have', 'a string', 'with', 'spaces', 'and we', 'have max', 'string', 'length']
```

You can combine the items with `"\n".join(output)`, print them, or do anything else that you wish.

Comment: Those list items dont have length of 8 chars !

Comment: @ghost21blade "divide string in rows with **max** b length in row, but we can divide **only** in space areas"

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for random strings... So it divide some string between word

Comment: So use break_long_words false, and break_hyphen false

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to write it yourself (rather than using *textwrap*) then:

```
def reformat(s, b):
    tokens = s.split()
    if len(tokens) > 0 and max(map(len, tokens)) <= b:
        result = [[tokens[0]]]
        for token in tokens[1:]:
            e = result[-1]
            if len(token) + sum(map(len, e)) + len(e) <= b:
                e.append(token)
            else:
                result.append([token])
        return [' '.join(e) for e in result]
s = 'we have a string with spaces and we have max string length'
print(*reformat(s, 8), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
we have
a string
with
spaces
and we
have max
string
length
```

Comment: Thank you, looks very clear. I will try rewrite len fucnc)